# error notice: Constant DB_NAME already defined in

Tags: php

i have file which both show a form and validate it. when showing the form everything is ok, but when i press the submit button so it validate the form, here i got error although the form is well validated, the error is :

```
notice: Constant DB_NAME already defined in C:\wamp\www\ssiphone\ss-config.php on line 15
```

THX for help :)

Comment: Which part of the error message in specific is making you hit the road-block?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be using [`include`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [`require`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) instead of [`include_once`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) or [`require_once`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).

If the file where `DB_NAME` is declared is being included more than once it would throw that error.  Otherwise you may just have multiple declarations in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've used, `include` or `require` to include the file and the file may contain constant value. Replace with,

```
require_once("FILE_PATH");
```

or

```
include_once("FILE_PATH");
```

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly what it says. You're defining a Constant called DB_NAME, and then trying to define it a second time. Look for this in files that you're including, which you should only be including once.... because my guess would be that you're defining in an included file.

Comment: THX, but how should i do tomake sure that my file is included once?

Comment: @Malek - Use include_once() rather than include()